# writing Regular expression for test data(PCRE)

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to write a regex that can match following criteria:

match everything after the first '@' and ':' that follows it. But it should not include these two characters. I have pasted my test data . I prefer using http://regexpal.com/ to test my regular expressions. 
For example if the test string is 
"pop3://abby@abby.com:43598743abby@173.201.192.199:110"

Then the regex should match "abby.com"

```
pop3://abby@abby.com:43598743abby@173.201.192.199:110
pop3://abby@abby.com:abby243234@173.201.192.199:110
smtp://tania@abby.ca:abby3@69.49.109.86:25
pop3://tania@abby.ca:abbya13@69.49.109.86:110
pop3://abby@abby.com:abby9675@173.201.193.199:110
pop3://abby@abby.com:abby12345@173.201.193.199:110
smtp://abby:820211ly520@202.108.6.242:25
pop3://smartinez@abby.com:abby123@64.26.60.221:110
```

Comment: I plan to write a Py script. but my main concern is to first filter out a large text file using Regular expression. Tools like Notepad++ support Regex searching so it will be easy for me to search and sort if I have the right regex.

Comment: Could you pls explain more detail regarding to `match everything after the first '@' and first ':' . But it should not include these two characters`

Comment: Oops. I guess I made a slight mistake in the question. Here is what I ment: Let us consider the first line of the example data set : "pop3://abby@supremefill.com:ash9675@173.201.192.199:110"  . I want to match "supremefill.com" . Anything after the first '@' and the next ':' that follows it.

Comment: let's say for first line , you want only `supremefill.com` ? which is between `@` and `:`

Comment: You got it Frank. I have modified my question. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Why do you tagged it `pcre`? The tool you linkd is using Javascript regexes. Do you know what you are doing?

Comment: Oh the tool link was for reference , in case someone wants to check the data set and corresponding regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=@)[^:]+
```

It matches a sequence of non ':' characters having a `@` in front of it. The `@` gets not included into the match.

https://regex101.com/r/pZ6xA5/1

Answer (score 3):

I'd simply use:

```
/@([^:]+):/
```

It matches string that is between `@` and `:`  the result is in group 1.

Comment: OP does not want @ and :

Comment: Yup, need to avoid @ :

Comment: @S.Krishna: These characters are not included in group 1. Did you try it?

Comment: @Toto yes I tried and I see that this regex matches @ and : too.. http://regexr.com/3b3ct

Comment: @S.Krishna These characters are not included in group 1! Do you even know what a capturing group is? If not, please learn that!

Comment: @hek2mgl, I dont and I will !

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you want to extract the domain of email addresses when the user name *is* an email address. To be more clear, the first line can be broken into these parts:

```
pop3://abby@supremefill.com:ash9675@173.201.192.199:110

[scheme] => pop3
[host]   => 173.201.192.199
[port]   => 110
[user]   => abby@supremefill.com
[pass]   => ash9675
```

So the user name is `abby@supremefill.com` and the domain of this email address is `supremefill.com`.

Note that for the line `smtp://liangyuan820211:820211ly520@202.108.6.242:25` the user name isn't an email address: `liangyuan820211`, then this line must not return any result.

An efficient way to extract the domain consists to anchor the pattern at the start of the line (to discard quickly useless positions where the pattern may be attempted) and by default the regex engine in notepad++ is set in multiline mode *(in this mode `^` stands for `start of the line`)*. To discard all the begining of the line until the domain name, you can use `\K`.

```
^[^@:]+:[^@:]+@\K[^:]+
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ7bU6/1)

Comment: Looks like the only *correct* answer here - having that the OP really wants that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `([a-z])*?\.([a-z])*`

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3b3ck)

Comment: Yup this matches perfectly. I just modified it slightly ([a-z])*?\.([a-z]){2,3}. This would pick up 2 or 3 length TLD. Thanks

Comment: This matches `foo.bar`. How is that related to the problem? How does it handle the `@` in front, how the `:` after the match?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=@)([^:\d]+):
```

more [detail](https://regex101.com/r/uL5dN2/1)

[image]

Comment: Why the capturing group? Why no numbers? (numbers *are* allowed in domain names. Why the `:` at the end?

Comment: It doesn't match the example given: `smtp://liangyuan820211:820211ly520@202.108.6.242:25`

Comment: Take a look again his question `For example if the test string is "pop3://abby@supremefill.com:ash9675@173.201.192.199:110"

Then the regex should match "supremefill.com"`